# Javascript array shows in console, but i cant access any properties in loops

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I really try my damndest not to ask, but i have to at this point before I tear my hair out.

By the time the js interpreter gets to this particular method, I can print it to the console no problem, it is an array of "event" objects. From FireBug I can see it, but when I try to set a loop to do anything with this array its as if it doesn't exist. I am absolutely baffled......

A few things:

I am a newbie, I have tried a `for(var index in list)` loop, to no avail, I have also tried a regular old `for(var i = 0; i < listIn.length; i++)`, and I also tried to get the size of the local variable by setting `var size = listIn.length`.

As soon as I try to loop through it I get nothing, but I can access all the objects inside it from the FireBug console no problem. Please help, even just giving me a little hint on where I should be looking would be great.

As for the array itself, I have no problems with getting an array back from PHP in the form of: `[{"Event_Id":"9", "Title":"none"}, etc etc ]`

Here is my code from my main launcher JavaScript file. I will also post a sample of the JSON data that is returned. I fear that I may be overextending myself by creating a massive object in the first place called `content`, which is meant to hold properties such as DOM strings, settings, and common methods, but so far everything else is working.

The `init()` function is called when the body `onload` is called on the corresponding html page, and during the call to `setAllEvents` and `setEventNavigation` I am lost.

And just to add, I am trying to learn JavaScript fundamentals before I ever touch jQuery.

Thanks

```
var dom, S, M, currentArray, buttonArray, typesArray, topicsArray;

content = {
    domElements: {},

    settings: {
        allContent: {},
        urlList: {
            allURL: "../PHP/getEventsListView.php",
            typesURL: "../PHP/getTypes.php",
            topicsURL: "../PHP/getTopics.php"
        },
        eventObjArray: [],
        buttonObjArray: [],
        eventTypesArray: [],
        eventTopicsArray: []
    },

    methods: {
        allCallBack: function (j) {
            S.allContent = JSON.parse(j);
            var list = S.allContent;
            for (var index in list) {
                var event = new Event(list[index]);
                S.eventObjArray.push(event);
            }
        },
        topicsCallBack: function(j) {
            S.eventTopicsArray = j;
            var list = JSON.parse(S.eventTopicsArray);
            topicsArray = list;
            M.populateTopicsDropDown(list);
        },
        typesCallBack: function(j) {
            S.eventTypesArray = j;
            var list = JSON.parse(S.eventTypesArray);
            typesArray = list;
            M.populateTypesDropDown(list);
        },
        ajax: function (url, callback) {
            getAjax(url, callback);
        },
        testList: function (listIn) {
           // test method
        },
        setAllEvents: function (listIn) {
            // HERE IS THE PROBLEM WITH THIS ARRAY
            console.log("shall we?");
            for(var index in listIn) {
                console.log(listIn[index]);
            }
        },
        getAllEvents: function () {
            return currentArray;
        },
        setAllButtons: function (listIn) {
            buttonArray = listIn;
        },
        getAllButtons: function () {
            return buttonArray;
        },
        setEventNavigation: function(current) {
            // SAME ISSUE AS ABOVE
            var l = current.length;
            //console.log("length " + l);
            var counter = 0;
            var endIndex = l - 1;
            if (current.length < 4) {
                switch (l) {
                    case 2:
                        var first = current[0];
                        var second = current[1];
                        first.setNextEvent(second);
                        second.setPreviousEvent(first);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        var first = current[0];
                        var second = current[1];
                        var third = current[2];
                        first.setNextEvent(second);
                        second.setPreviousEvent(first);
                        second.setNextEvent(third);
                        third.setPreviousEvent(second);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            } else {
                // do something
            }
        },
        populateTopicsDropDown: function(listTopics) {
            //console.log("inside topics drop");
            //console.log(listTopics);
            var topicsDropDown = document.getElementById("eventTopicListBox");
            for(var index in listTopics) {
                var op = document.createElement("option");
                op.setAttribute("id", "dd" + index);
                op.innerHTML = listTopics[index].Main_Topic;
                topicsDropDown.appendChild(op);
            }
        },
        populateTypesDropDown: function(listTypes) {
            //console.log("inside types drodown");
            //console.log(listTypes);
            var typesDropDown = document.getElementById("eventTypeListBox");
            for(var index2 in listTypes) {
                var op2 = document.createElement("option");
                op2.setAttribute("id", "dd2" + index2);
                op2.innerHTML = listTypes[index2].Main_Type;
                typesDropDown.appendChild(op2);
            }
        }
    },
    init: function() {
        dom = this.domElements;
        S = this.settings;
        M = this.methods;
        currentArray = S.eventObjArray;
        buttonArray = S.buttonObjArray;
        topicsArray = S.eventTopicsArray;
        typesArray = S.eventTypesArray;
        M.ajax(S.urlList.allURL, M.allCallBack);
        //var tempList = currentArray;
        //console.log("temp array length: " + tempList.length);
        M.setAllEvents(currentArray);
        M.testList(currentArray);
        M.setEventNavigation(currentArray);
        //M.setEventNavigation();
        M.ajax(S.urlList.topicsURL, M.topicsCallBack);
        M.ajax(S.urlList.typesURL, M.typesCallBack);
    }
};
```

Comment: Sample currentArray:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have is that `currentArray` gets its value asynchronously, which means you are calling `setAllEvents` too soon. At that moment the `allCallBack` function has not yet been executed. That happens only after the current running code has completed (until call stack becomes emtpy), and the `ajax` request triggers the callback.

So you should call `setAllEvents` and any other code that depends on `currentArray` only when the Ajax call has completed.

NB: The reason that it works in the console is that by the time you request the value from the console, the ajax call has already returned the response.

Without having looked at the rest of your code, and any other problems that it might have, this solves the issue you have:

```
init: function() {
    dom = this.domElements;
    S = this.settings;
    M = this.methods;
    currentArray = S.eventObjArray;
    buttonArray = S.buttonObjArray;
    topicsArray = S.eventTopicsArray;
    typesArray = S.eventTypesArray;
    M.ajax(S.urlList.allURL, function (j) {
        // Note that all the rest of the code is moved in this call back 
        // function, so that it only executes when the Ajax response is
        // available:
        M.allCallBack(j);
        //var tempList = currentArray;
        //console.log("temp array length: " + tempList.length);
        M.setAllEvents(currentArray);
        M.testList(currentArray);
        M.setEventNavigation(currentArray);
        //M.setEventNavigation();
        // Note that you will need to take care with the following asynchronous
        // calls as well: their effect is only available when the Ajax
        // callback is triggered:
        M.ajax(S.urlList.topicsURL, M.topicsCallBack); //
        M.ajax(S.urlList.typesURL, M.typesCallBack);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you SO much. That makes huge sense now. if i am learning this straight, even though the server returns an ajax response pretty quick, originally it wasnt quite quick enough to return a value for the currentArray var being that the interpreter ran down through that code so quick? Much appreciated

Comment: You're welcome. Just to be more exact: the ajax response *could never* be fast enough, because it is asynchronous. Even if the response would be almost immediate, the asynchronous mechanism is such that the callback *can only* be called when your currently running code has finished running.